# Isabelle: performance issues with version Isabelle2013-2

Tags: java, linux, performance, isabelle

I have performance issues in Isabelle (i.e., the resent version Isabelle2013-2).
I use **Isabelle/JEdit**, based on the new interface.

So before, the situation was I had some trouble with the performance. But now it is worse, as I sometimes have to wait up to 10 seconds sometimes to enter the right. The performance issues get worse over time, to the point were I have to restart Isabelle after an hour or so.

My suspicion is that I can configure Isabelle better or apply some tricks that improve the performance.

**Hardware:**
recent CPU, it's an intel i7 quadcore (mobile labtop chip), 16GB ram, fast SSD harddisk.

**Software:**
64bit arch linux (kernel 3.12.5-1-ARCH)
no 32bit compatibility libraries
my java version is:

```
   java version "1.7.0_45"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.3) (ArchLinux build 7.u45_2.4.3-1-x86_64)
```

My theory file has the size `125KB`, the whole theory I am working is in one file, but at the moment I would really want to have just one file.

**Symptoms:**
Isabelle displays only about 900mb in the lower right corner of UI. I have 16GB RAM, should I configure java to use more RAM? Sometimes a singe process consumes 600% of the CPU, i.e., 6 cores that the linux kernel sees.

**Tricks I use:**

One trick is that I insert `*)` at a line below the code I am working on. This leads to a syntax error and the below code is not checked. The second trick is that I went to the timing panel, and all proofs that took longer than 0.2 seconds I commented out and replaced with `sorry`.

The resent two Isabelle versions are really great improvements!

Any suggestions or tricks to how I can improve the performance of Isabelle?

Comment: please comment if I need to clarify my performance issues or need to provide details.

Comment: why do you want to close this? Performance tricks are likely to be valid for future Isabelle versions too.

Comment: Perf problems with the PIDE will be ongoing for years; they're more of a bug-type report. From appearances, there's only 1 person who singlehandedly develops Isa/jEdit, which is Wenzel. He also seems to track down problems that aren't necessarily his fault which other devs report, which involve Isa/jEdit. He generally responds on the isa-mail-list for bug-type reports. On the isa-mail-list, I think it's pretty well known that Isa2013-2 didn't get it completely right. I already reported several things which can totally hang the PIDE, but that's part of progress. I take the good with the bad.

Comment: You being the software type, you might want to get set up to use the latest repository version, which will have fixes the release won't have. I just wait for the next release.

Answer (score 2):

A few general hints on performance tuning:

- One needs to distinguish Isabelle/ML (i.e. the underlying Poly/ML runtime) versus Isabelle/Scala (i.e. the underlying JVM).
- Isabelle/ML: Intel CPUs like i7 have hyperthreading, which virtually doubles the number of cores.  On smaller mobile machines it is usually better to restrict the nominal number of cores to half of that.  See the "threads" option in Isabelle/jEdit / Plugin Options / Isabelle / General.  When running on batteries you might even go further below.
- Isabelle/ML: Using x86 (32bit) Poly/ML generally improves performance.  This is only relevant to Linux, because that platform usually lacks x86 libraries that other platforms provide routinely.  There is rarely any benefit to fall back on bulky x86_64.  Poly/ML 5.5.x is very good at working in the constant space of 32bit mode.
- Isabelle/Scala: JVM performance can be improved by using native x86_64 (which is the default) and providing generous stack and heap parameters.

  - The main Isabelle application bundle bootstraps the JVM with some options that are hard-wired in a certain place, which can be edited nonetheless:

    - Linux: Isabelle2013-2/Isabelle2013-2.run
    - Windows: Isabelle2013-2/Isabelle2013-2.ini
    - Mac OS X: Isabelle2013-2.app/Contents/Info.plist

    For example, the maximum heap size can be changed from `-Xmx1024m` to `-Xmx4096m`.
  - The `isabelle jedit` command-line tool is configured via the Isabelle settings environment.  See also `$ISABELLE_HOME/src/Tools/etc/settings` for some examples of `JEDIT_JAVA_OPTIONS`, which can be copied to `$ISABELLE_HOME_USER/etc/settings` and adapted accordingly.  It is also possible to monitor JVM performance via `jconsole` to get an idea if that is actually a source of problems.
- Isabelle/Scala: Isabelle bundles a certain JVM, which is assumed here by default.  This variable elimination of Java versions is important to regain some sanity --- otherwise you never know what you get.  Are you sure that your OpenJDK is actually used here?  It is unlikely, unless you have edited some Isabelle settings.

Further sources of performance problems on Linux is graphics.  Java/AWT is known to be much slower on X11 than on Windows and Mac OS X.  Using the quasi-native GTK look-and-feel on Linux degrades graphics performance even further.